# Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Angular 5, HTTP Binance

Tags: angular, angular5

I am trying to run the basic public API of Binance. https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price

When I open it in the browser, it works fine, but when I use it in my Angular code. I get the error Access-Control-Allow-Origin. I tried adding it in my header as well to avoid it, but that doesn't work. This is my code.

```
 headers1 = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type' });

  getData() {
    return this.http.get('http://www.api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price', { headers: this.headers1 });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is server side, you need the Binance api to allow `CORS` header to have angular be able to grab data.

Answer (score 0):

Binance dont support direct browser usage of their API, you need to implement a server who get the data from Binance and send them to your application.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the headers' `'Content-Type'`.

The `'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type'` is server side, you don't need to set that either.